# Doesn't work focus on a textarea in javascript, ASP.net application

Tags: javascript, html

I have a grid and a textarea.When I click on a line from the grid ,in the textarea control  I put some informations and I want this textarea to be in the front of the page , because my grid have multiple lines and my textarea is down on the page.
The definition for textarea is this:

```
<textarea id="BodyMessDetailed"  cols="20" name="S1" rows="10" readonly="readonly"    tabindex="1" >
   <%=DefaultVal%>
</textarea>
```

In the row definition I call ShowBodyFunction:

```
<tr onclick ="javascript:ShowBody('B<% = Model.Id  %>')"> ....
```

ShowBodyFunction is :

```
function ShowBody(stringId) {
           var obj1
           var obj2

           obj1 = document.getElementById(stringId);
           obj2 = document.getElementById("BodyMessDetailed");
           obj2.innerText = obj1.innerText;
           obj2.select();
           obj2.focus();


       }
```

I observed that if I click on the line of the grid and after that I press backspace the application does what I want ,but I don't know how to make this from application .I tried with : onclick ="javascript:ShowBody('B<% = Model.Id  %>');tab char;" >

but doesn't work.Can somebody tell my which is the solution?

Can somebody tell me how to call a backspace or a tab  after I call the 'ShowBody' function?

Answer (score 0):

try replacing innerText method by innerHTML and comment the obj.select() method. If it doesn't works after that tell me.

Answer (score 0):

please make one more change -
replace:
    ')">
by:

```
<tr onclick="ShowBody(this.id)" id="" .....
```

The 'id' attribute is mandatory in the 'TR' element.

Hope it works this time :)

Answer (score 0):

in the function **showBody**, comment everything you have previously written and

just put an **`alert(StringID);`** inside it and see if the function is getting called or not.

If the function is not getting called there is no use of looking what's written inside it.

If the alert dialog shows up during the runtime, then we will look into actual code inside

ShowBody. I'm online :)    .

Comment: the function is called , because in that function I fill textarea with some text and the text is correct but the page doesn't refresh with my textarea on the shown area on the page and I have to scroll down to see what is wrote in there

Comment: Or, If when I run the application if it works fine, when I press a backspace or a tab do you know how to simulate this from code ? After i run the function ShowBody how to add a backspace or a tab ?

Comment: It was a problem   in the 'ShowBody' function and never arrive to obj2.focus.Thanks a lot for help!  I modify code : obj2 = document.getElementById("BodyMessDetailed");
               obj2.focus(); and it's ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Just make use of `value` its working fine.

```
function ShowBody(stringId) {
    alert(stringId); // showing the output
    var obj1 = document.getElementById(stringId);
    var obj2 = document.getElementById("BodyMessDetailed");
    obj2.value = obj1.value;
    obj2.select();
    obj2.focus();

    obj2.scrollIntoView();
}
```

put a `semicolon` in `function call` in `tr`.

```
<tr onclick ="ShowBody('B<% = Model.Id  %>');">
```

attaching screen shot for your reference

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The function is called in my application  , because in that function I fill textarea with some text and the text appear ,but the  textarea doesn't appear on the part of the page that is shown  and I have to scroll down to see what is wrote in there.I have a list with many lines and down I have this textarea  and when a user click on a line the textarea is completed with some text and this must be on first screen ,  the user right now must scroll till down of the page  and i want that this text to be shown in the visible part  of the screen .

Comment: I modified function ShowBody in that way and now it's ok : : function ShowBody(stringId) {
               var obj1
               var obj2

              
               obj1 = document.getElementById(stringId);
               obj2 = document.getElementById("BodyMessDetailed");
               obj2.focus();
               obj2.innerText = obj1.innerText;
               obj2.style.borderColor = Purple;

           }   Thanks a lot

Comment: add "obj2.scrollIntoView();" in the code. updated the code.. try it

Comment: Yes , you give me some hints , because I try to solve this problem for 2 days and I was no ideeas what to try :)